# ngModel reference when pushed into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pushing a new order into the customer.orders array and everything works fine but it seems to reference the ngModel because if I now type something into the neworder.product model it updates the view at customer.orders.product. It seems to reset itself on refresh.

Any ideas?

Some Code:

```
$scope.currentCustomer.orders.push($scope.newOrder);
```

The newOrder form:

```
<form id="newOrder" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="month" ng-model="newOrder.date" />
    <div>
      <label ng-repeat="product in products">
        {{product}}
        <input type="number" ng-model="newOrder[product]" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button>
        Add Order
    </button>
</form>
```

I display my orders:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in currentCustomer.orders">
      <span class="header">
        {{order.date}}
      </span>
      <span ng-repeat="product in products">     
          {{product}}: {{order[products]}} 
      </span>
</div>
```

What happens:
1) Enter a new order and press enter.
2) Enter a new order.
3) All orders above get updated while typing? I don't understand because the ngModel is different?

I tried angular.copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same data object for all customer' orders. Use Angular' [`copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) method, this way every order will have its own unique object:

```
$scope.currentCustomer.orders.push( angular.copy($scope.newOrder) );
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZnML/

Comment: @Lorof i like to solve issues with Angular , this way i'm learning too! ;)

Comment: @Lorof now i see this line , good that i didn't see it before , otherwise i could not check this option..